# Read linear encoder with 40.000 pulses/second Raspberry Pi B+

Tags: raspbian

I need the following sensor as a positional reference for a vertical moving platform:

https://www.siko-global.com/adbimage/1712/asset_original/data-sheet-msk2000.pdf

The encoder has a linear resolution of 0.25 mm, which generates 40.000 pulses/second when using a maximum speed of 10 m/second (the platform is moved by hand, so it should be less than this in average).

Is the raspberry pi fast enough to work with 40000 interrupts/second??? (I think that is what I need to manage if I'm moving with 10m/second, correct me if I'm wrong)

I've done a quick test using the wiringPi library and I did not get back to the initial value, when I moved the platform back to initial position. It worked, when I was moving the platform really slow, but that's not my aim.

My ideas now are to use the pigpio library (I'm writing in c) or to use an arduino board just for reading the encoder (as worst case solution). Are there any other solutions?

I've also read about quadrature decoding ICs. What that be a possible solution?

Thanks in advance :)

Best regards,

Niko

Comment: Linux on the Pi can't handle an interrupt every 25 µs to userland (it takes >50 µs to wake-up a userland process).  pigpio samples so will capture the events.  Whether the rest of the software can keep up or not is down to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some pigpio encoder examples.

1. [Python](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_rotary_encoder_py) at abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_rotary_encoder_py
2. [C](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2_RED.) but using the daemon at abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2_RED.

   The C code uses the same interface as Python but can handle far higher rotation rates. Python implementation did it for me , however my encoder has 1000 pulses/revolution

Comment: Thanks :) I will try that and give some feedback if it works :)

Comment: Just a short feedback:
I have chosen this IC to solve my problem and it works great:
http://www.mikroe.com/click/counter/